# ORACLE / Select the records that only has the value X on Column_B

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following scenario:

Table1

```
ID  Column_B
10001   X
10001   Y
10002   X
10003   X
10003   Y
10004   X
10005   X
10005   Y
```

I need to do a query that shows the IDs that has only X on Column_B, so the result would be:

```
10002   X
10004   X
```

If I run the select below, it shows also the records that has Y on Column_B:

```
select ID, Column_B from Table1 where Column_B = 'X'

ID  Column B
10001   X
10002   X
10003   X
10004   X
10005   X
```

I couldn't find anything similar to this case, anywhere. Losing my mind here trying to figure it out. It seems to be so simple. Damn.

Comment: Did you try to use the 'group by' clause?

Comment: Yes, I did. But even with group by it still shows the records with 'Y' on Column_B. The solution was to use the minus operator. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relational algebra - in this case, `MINUS`:

```
SELECT ID
  FROM TABLE1
  WHERE COLUMN_B = 'X'
MINUS
  SELECT ID
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE COLUMN_B = 'Y';
```

You start with a list of all the ID's which are associated with 'X', and subtract off the list of ID's which are associated with 'Y'.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7631/4)

Best of luck.

Comment: Bingo!!! I did not work with the MINUS operator before... It works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. When I went back and looked at this I realized I'd used subqueries where they were unnecessary, so I've cleaned up the query and the SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(column_b) = max(column_b) and min(column_b) = 'X';
```

Comment: I tried to use this aggregation, but the result still shows the ids with 'Y' on Column_B. Just don't know why... Thank you anyway!

Comment: @cariaG . . . This logic can really only show `'X'` and `NULL`.